# Download Zip From Different Path using Php

Tags: php, file, zip, file-get-contents, file-put-contents

If i have a path like below:

```
"/sites/main/files/myfile.zip"
```

How can I download the file using PHP?

I tried something like below but nothing happens. Anyone has any ideas?

```
$myzipfile =  "/sites/main/files/myfile.zip";
file_put_contents("myfile.zip", file_get_contents( $myzipfile ));
```

Comment: Sorry your question is not clear. I dont see anywhere where you are DOWNLOADING anything. Can you add some clearer explanation of your problem please

Comment: @RiggsFolly i just see online and follow the code as above. is that code not to download? if not then can you suggest a way to download via php?

Comment: Are you trying to send a file to the client PC or get a file from the client PC to the server

Comment: @RiggsFolly I want to get a file from the server to the client pc